# Only allow 2 Buttons to be pressed

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a matching card application. That only allows the user to select two cards per round.

[image: IMAGE OF THE APPLICATION]
Where you see the bricks are where the buttons are and so i have added them to an arraylist, but im not sure how to make it so that they can only press 2 buttons until they press the guess button where it checks if they are a match.

https://pastebin.com/65NqJ0GK

```
    private void card1ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String temp = cards.get(0);

    if (temp.equals("0")) {
        card1Button.setIcon(a);
    } else if (temp.equals("1")) {
        card1Button.setIcon(b);
    } else if (temp.equals("2")) {
        card1Button.setIcon(c);
    } else if (temp.equals("3")) {
        card1Button.setIcon(d);
    } else if (temp.equals("4")) {
        card1Button.setIcon(e);
    } else if (temp.equals("5")) {
        card1Button.setIcon(f);
    } else if (temp.equals("6")) {
        card1Button.setIcon(g);
    } else if (temp.equals("7")) {
        card1Button.setIcon(h);
    }

    count++;
    if (count == 1) {
        c1 = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        change[0] = 0;
    } else if (count == 2) {
        c2 = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        change[0] = 0;
    }


}
```

^^Here is an example of a button code.
Could someone show me some way to do it.

Comment: You're always increasing `count`, never resetting it

Comment: @cricket_007 I reset it in the guess method

Comment: Use two `ButtonGroups`, with one "match" in each

Comment: You should if the count > 2 then don't set the Icon.  Also, think about have one actionPerformed method for all the cards and inside there figure out which card was clicked based on the name of the button and then handle the logic. You have a lot of repeated code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer so if I have two button groups how do I check if there are 2 buttons that have been pressed.

Comment: A single button group would only allow a single button to be selected in it. You can check the `getSelection` method of each group, if both are not `null`, then two buttons have been pressed

Comment: @MadProgrammer is doesnt let me do getSelection do you mean .get()

Comment: @Alice No, I mean [`ButtonGroup#getSelection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#getSelection--)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i see, but whenever i select a button it still gives me null for both. Is that normal?

Comment: @MadProgrammer 'System.out.println(buttonGroup1.getSelection()); 
System.out.println(buttonGroup2.getSelection());' This is how i check if they are null, is this correct?

Comment: Are you adding the buttons to the groups? See [How to use Button Groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html)